# How to get successive values during recursion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion

I give some PROB values and the x=5. How can I get the value of M when x=5,x=4,... and store it separately? I tried the following but it did not work. Please help out.

```
function [ M,P ] = Recursion( PROB,lambda,x)

 if x==1
    M=exp(-lambda);

 else if x>1
        L=0;
        for i=1:x-1
            L=L+(i*PROB(:,i));
        end
        M=(lambda/(x-1))*L*Recursion(PROB,lambda,x-1);
        P=[];
        P=[P;M];

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some code like this. You need to also get `P` from the recursive call of your function.

```
function [ M,P ] = Recursion( PROB,lambda,x)

if x == 1
    M = exp(-lambda);
    P = M;
else
    if x > 1
        L = 0;
        for i = 1:x-1
            L = L+(i*PROB(:,i));
        end
        [M,P] = Recursion(PROB,lambda,x-1);
        M = (lambda/(x-1))*L*M;
        P = [P;M];
    end
end
```